# rxjs and typescript return an function with no parameters

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to use rxjs with amqplib to convert the received messages from rabbit to a stream of messages:

```
const connection = await amqplib.connect(constr);
const channel = await connection.createChannel();
const callBack: any = bindCallback(channel.consume);
const observalble = callBack("queue");
```

the problem is callBack returned from bindCallback is a method with no parameters..
what am is doing wrong here?

I depended on the example:

```
// From a callback (last argument is a callback)
// fs.exists = (path, cb(exists))
var exists = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(fs.exists);
exists('file.txt').subscribe(exists => console.log('Does file exist?', exists));
```

form the rxjs documentation...

please help

im using rxjs 6.5.2
typescript 3.4.5
amqplib 0.5.2

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
const connection = await amqplib.connect(constr);
const channel = bindCallback(connection.createChannel);
channel().subscribe(args => {
    const err = args[0]
    const ch = args[1]
    if(err) throw err

    const ch_observable = bindCallback(ch.consume)
    ch_observable("queue").subscribe(msg => {
        console.log(msg)
    })

})
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I just tried to use callback api instead of Promise Api from `amqlib`. I just had the same issue with other modules. The callback style API worked but the Promise Api did not. If I knew I would have written it in answer ofc :)

Comment: I just came over this, Read through all docs fastly, and answered from scratch. I do not have any experience using `amqlib`, and I have little experience in `rxjs`. DOn't have time to go deeper sry.